Triple-booting Windows NT 4.x/5.x, Windows 9x, and MS-DOS using NTLDR
I was pretty sure booting a non-NT OS (DOS, Windows 9x, and even Linux) via NTLDR was as simple as just extracting the boot sector (the VBR) into c:\bootsect.dos and declaring something like this in c:\boot.ini:
[boot loader]
timeout=0
default=C:\

[operating systems]
C:\ = "MS-DOS 6.22"

Recently, I came across Boot INI Options Reference, published back in 2006 and still available online, which lists two boot.ini options I've never used previously:


/WIN95
Directs Ntldr to boot the Consumer Windows boot sector stored in
Bootsect.w40. This switch is pertinent only on a triple-boot system
that has MS-DOS, Consumer Windows, and Windows installed. See
Microsoft Knowledge Base article Q157992 for more information.

/WIN95DOS
Directs Ntldr to boot the MS-DOS boot sector stored in Bootsect.dos.
This switch is pertinent only on a triple-boot system that has
MS-DOS, Consumer Windows, and Windows installed. See Microsoft
Knowledge Base article Q157992 for more information.



Yet, Q157992 tells nothing new except

The new switches, /win95dos and /win95, are needed so that Windows NT can emulate the multiple boot process of Windows 95/98.

What it doesn't tell in particular is now to resolve name conflicts between io.sys, io.dos, and io.w40 (and their msdos.{sys,dos,w40} and command.{com,dos,w40} counterparts) when switching from Windows 9x to DOS and vice versa.
Questions:

What exactly /win95dos and /win95 switches are needed for? I've successfully booted MS-DOS, Windows 9x, Linux and even Solaris/x86 like hundreds of times, w/o any extra switches. Yet, I can confirm these switches do make some difference: a Windows 98 VBR indeed can't be combined with an explicit /win95dos switch (the boot process simply doesn't go beyond the black-screen-with-a-blinking-cursor stage).
How do I triple-boot Windows NT 4.x/5.x, Windows 9x, and MS-DOS from the same primary partition (C:) of a single hard drive, using NTLDR? Yes I'm aware Windows 9x boot loader can boot "your previous operating system" (which happens to be MS-DOS) via Windows 9x boot menu, but how do I do that via boot.ini? Microsoft claim this is possible, they can't be mistaken, right?


MS-DOS v6 load protocol uses the msdos file passed in a directory entry at 00520h in memory. If NTLDR modifies the name within the boot sector loader, or skips that and loads msload + the two directory entries by itself then it can boot from names other than io.sys and msdos.sys

@ecm, thank you for your comment. I actually thought about manually modifying io.sys and msdos.sys entries in the DOS boot sector (there's plenty of room for an experiment), but I'm looking for a supported and/or well-documented way to triple-boot. By msload you're referring to Win9x boot process, right?

No, msload is the "Non-Contiguous IBMBIO Loader (MSLOAD)", I wrote about it some on my blog. The msload stage is the initial loader stored in the first 1536 bytes of io.sys. (The MS-DOS v7 boot load protocol changed the msload length to 2048 bytes.) The boot sector has to load msload to 00700h for both v6 + v7. In v4 its start cluster must be cluster 2.

To load a boot sector image, the boot menu entry in the [operating systems] section of BOOT.INI should contain a DOS-style pathname starting with “C:\” pointing to the boot sector image file to use.  If the pathname is just “C:\”, with no boot sector file specified, NTLDR will use BOOTSECT.DOS by default.  If the pathname points to a directory instead, NTLDR will take this to mean Windows NT is supposed to be booted instead.
Any 512-byte0 file will be accepted as a boot sector image and NTLDR will not interfere with its contents at all; not even the 55AA signature is checked.  NTLDR might as well chainload a boot sector of a different partition, or LILO, or F-Bird.  NTLDR simply transfers control to the boot sector image at its customary address of 0000:7C00 and then leaves it on its own, with the DX register which identifies the boot device receiving a fixed value of 0x80 (referring to the first hard drive).
As for the switches, this is what I can tell about their behaviour: for each of the boot file names: IO.SYS, MSDOS.SYS, CONFIG.SYS, COMMAND.COM and AUTOEXEC.BAT1, the /WIN95 switch has NTLDR perform the following steps before loading the boot sector:

Check if a file exists with that name with the extension replaced by “.W40”.  (IO.SYS is special-cased to use the alternative name “WINBOOT.SYS” instead.)  If it does not, skip the rest of these steps.
If a file exists under the original boot file name, rename it to have the extension “.DOS”.  Otherwise, skip the next step.
Rename the file with the alternative name checked in step (0) to the original boot file name.

/WIN95DOS has the opposite effect: original boot files are renamed to have the extension “.W40” (with “IO.SYS”, again, exceptionally renamed to “WINBOOT.SYS” instead), while “.DOS” files take their place.  If neither switch is passed, no renaming shenanigans should occur.  This mirrors the behaviour of the dual-booting feature built into Windows 95 itself, which performs similar renaming.
As such, the combination of /WIN95 for one NTLDR menu entry and /WIN95DOS for another allows booting two different versions of MS-DOS from the same FAT file system; clearly /WIN95 was intended to boot MS-DOS 7.0 while /WIN95DOS was meant for booting MS-DOS 6 that the former version was installed on top of, but this is not relied on too much, so it’s possible to create other set-ups.
That said, again, other than renaming the boot files, NTLDR still does not assist the boot sector image in any way.  All of the usual constraints that the boot sector code places on the file system still apply, and successful start-up will depend on that boot sector image being able to correctly load any further boot stages itself, with no other help from NTLDR.  In particular, the boot sector of MS-DOS up to version 6.22 requires the first two entries of the root directory to be IO.SYS and MSDOS.SYS, and the first three sectors of the former have to be laid out contiguously (later versions can load IO.SYS / WINBOOT.SYS from any directory slot).  Boot code for all MS-DOS versions (including 7.x and 8.x) needs the BPB structure to contain the correct geometry for the drive, the correct “hidden sectors” value equalling the partition offset, and so on.

0 If the file is 8 KiB in size, NTLDR will instead take it to be an image of the boot area of an NTFS or HPFS file system – judging by it checking if the OEM ID matches “NTFS” and the entry point addresses of 0D00:0256 or 0D00:0200, which happen to match those used by boot code stored in UNTFS.DLL and UHPFS.DLL of Windows NT 3.51 – but neither of these file systems are supported by Windows 9x or MS-DOS, so they do not concern us here.
1 “The NTLDR Hacking Guide” from 1996 by Jason C. Locke claims CONFIG.SYS and AUTOEXEC.BAT files were not renamed by the version of NTLDR he tested, but from my checking it seems that NTLDR of Windows NT as early as 3.51 does look for them.  NT 3.1 does not seem to have the renaming functionality at all, which should not be surprising, although it does already seem to look for BOOTSECT.DOS, so perhaps chainloading boot sectors was supported back then.

I just rechecked the bootloader in the boot disk image at https://archive.org/download/ms-dos-6.22_20220302 and it definitely requires the two kernel files to be in the first two directory entries. The Q66530 article that you linked also doesn't seem to say anything about v5/v6 not needing the system files in the first two directory entries.

MS-DOS v7 does allow its io.sys or jo.sys or winboot.sys in any directory entry however. But the boot sector loader depends on 186+ instructions. (MS-DOS v7 msload also depends on 386+ instructions I can confirm.)

Hmm, I assumed as much based on the article not mentioning that again for MS-DOS 5. But it seems you are right – only MS-DOS 7 dropped that directory slot requirement.

For the record, https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66530/ is the link you removed in the edit.

@ecm Have you got a detailed write-up of how the MS-DOS boot protocol works anywhere? What stages there are, what assumptions are made, and what they need to have loaded in memory to proceed further? Because I keep wondering if perhaps it would have been possible to read IO.SYS and MSDOS.SYS from disk in their entirety, relocate them in memory and hand over control to the DOS kernel directly, bypassing MSLOAD entirely.

The sector to initial loader ones are documented in my lDOS boot manual. I wrote about a problem with the msdos file on my blog. You could load msbio (the next stage loaded by msload) to 700h, enter at 70h:0, but you'd need to know the exact byte offset of it in the io.sys file (it isn't aligned), unsure about registers. And msdos.sys is loaded much later, you'd have to patch msbio to make use of a resident msdos.

In my fork of MS-DOS v4.01 https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/msdos4/ I replaced msload by a single-file solution using lDOS iniload/drload, optional inicomp stage, and drkernpl which places and enters msbio.

For bypassing msload it probably helps to study the msload passing control to msbio. This revision in my repo is the last of the msload/msbio/msdos dual-file setup, but it does already have build fixes and creates .tls (trace listing) files useful for debugging. According to this the registers are ax:bx = data start including hidden sectors, ch = media ID, dl = int 13h unit, and of course the msdos file's directory entry must still be at 00520h.
